# Ruby on Rails : Find record of an object without querying database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to know how to get a specific record from an object example

```
@user = User.all
```

In `index.html.erb`,  I want to show only the record that in the 3rd order , I try, but this gives me all the records. :

```
<% @user.each do |u| %>
```

I found this :

```
<% @user.find{|b| b.id == 1}%>
  <%= @service.full_name%>
```

But didn't work and I don't know how to use it right in `index.html.erb`

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can take array element directly in template. For reason – if you need all another users to

```html
<div class="super-user">
   <%= @users[3].name %>
</div>

<div class="other-users">
  <% @users.each do |u| %>
    <a href="#">Destroy Him!</a>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

If you don't need all another users, prefer to don't fetch them all. Use `find` or `find_by` methods e.g.

```ruby
@user = User.find(4) # finds user by id=4
```

or

```
@user = User.find_by(name: 'user', admin: true) # finds by hash arguments
```

or even

```
# fetch direcly 3-th user from database
@user = User.order(:id).limit(1).offset(2).first
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html

Comment: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Sorry. little fix on  @users[3].name instead of  @user[3].name. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just write

```
@user = User.all.third
```

Boris is right though just returning all the records is a bad practice. It may not be noticeable at this point in time but as the amount of  `User` records in your database grow this query will get proportionally slower. So the better option is

```
@user = User.third
```